# removing '\n' before a keyword in a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

I have the following string:

```py
elements = "one: Fire \n two: Water \n three: Earth \n four: \n Sky \n five: \n Light \n"
```

I want to dynamically split lines to end up with a dictionary shape like the following:

```py
{one: Fire, 
two: Water, 
three: Earth, 
four: Sky, 
five: Light}
```

I'm able to do it for the first three elements using `re.findall()` as the information is contained before the new line split. 
However for "four:" and "five:" there is a "\n" before the element and I'm not able to extract the element.

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Only solution I can think of is to filter the "\n" before a list of element words.

Comment: How about [`re.split(r' *\n(?= *\w+:) *', elements)`](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIwEEP3fMWpS5uCWNgiVUx0YmNg6dLhICfaJLocVP36kERisp9s2WEX6905JVqDZwFGpXDBFZ1EGKDxDg2MxAiTA9m8gccsyJUsYw6vM4st/PQfNsXc33tl@mLlG72sZNMoxjLKeIphIem4hX5y3WXIsh2Mhr49wv9dq8DkcgmjTukH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need a complex regex to do this. You could just try this

```py
str = 'one: Fire \n two: Water \n three: Earth \n four: \n Sky \n five: \n Light \n'
str = str.replace(' ', '').replace(':\n', ':')
parts = filter(lambda x: ':' in x, str.split('\n'))
elements = dict((elem.split(':')) for elem in parts)
print(elements)
```

But if you really want to be fancy, this would also work

```py
import re
str = 'one: Fire \n two: Water \n three: Earth \n four: \n Sky \n five: \n Light \n'
parts = map(lambda x: re.sub('\s', '', x), re.findall('\w+:\s*\w+', str))
elements = dict((elem.split(':')) for elem in parts)
print(elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more concise way, but you can do:

```
re.findall(r".*: [a-zA-Z\s]+ \n", elements)
```

to get all of thee elements.

To get it into a dict you could do something like:

```
split_elems = re.findall(r".*: [a-zA-Z\s]+ \n", elements)
stripped_elems = [elem.strip() for elem in split_elems]
dict((elem.split(':')) for elem in stripped_elems)
```

Or, as @eva-vw pointed out, you can do this if you want to remove the whitespace from the values:

```
{elem.split(':')[0]: elem.split(':')[1].strip() for elem in stripped_elems}
```

Comment: There are still some leftover new lines in that dict. You can get them all out with: ```{e.split(':')[0].strip(): e.split(':')[1].strip().split()[0] for e in re.findall(r".*: [a-zA-Z\s]+ \n", elements)}```. Nice `re` answer thanks for sharing!